# ofxEtherdream compile on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, visual-studio-2015, openframeworks

I just started to learn openFrameworks and it's great! I love it. But now I'm stuck.. badly. Can't find anything on the web, and maybe I miss a bit of programming skills for this problem.

Here is my question:
I'm on a project, internship, involving openFrameworks and ofxEtherdream. I started coding on my Linux laptop, and it's going well.
Though, the final project needs to run on Windows, and etherdream.c uses Linux only libraries.. so I can't just compile this program with Visual Studio without linking the dll... how do I do that ?

Here is the source code for Etherdream:
https://github.com/j4cbo/j4cDAC/tree/master/driver/libetherdream

Here is the ofxEtherdream project, the one I need to compile on Windows.
https://github.com/memo/ofxEtherdream

I really need this to work! Is there a way to either:

- Compile ofxEtherdream on Windows?
- Find a Windows version of the source code? (Why does etherdream.dll exists but no source code for Windows is available?)
- Link etherdream.dll to my Visual Studio project and being able to tell Visual Studio to ignore the current etherdream.c/h in the lib folder of the ofxEtherdream, which is referenced in ofxEtherdream.cpp?
- ...?? any other solution I'm not aware

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to the same issue and decided to make a c++ interface that wraps the etherdream dll for windows. I wasn't able to compile the source from scratch so decided to run with the dll instead. Could be of interest. I've successfully used it on a variety of projects without any issues: https://github.com/naivisoftware/netherdream

Unfortunately there's only a x32 build of the dll. I wanted to use it in a 64 bit environment but no luck there. Have been in touch with the ether dream developer and was promised an update. Unfortunately I haven't seen anything yet. Note that the interface mentioned above has only been tested with the first version of the ether-dream DAC and dll.

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate builds of libetherdream, one is windows, one is linux/mac. ofxEtherdream is linked against the linux/mac version. The windows C driver can be found here, but I think someone would have to re-implement ofxEtherdream and link against the windows lib:

https://github.com/j4cbo/j4cDAC/tree/master/driver/